# Prove this A∆B=C <=> B∆C=A

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic, boolean-algebra

$A∆B=C <=> B∆A=C$
I don't idea. Is this correct task? Maybe the <=> means something else i don't know?

Comment: You say you "don't idea", and I [don't believe you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Begin with what you think $\iff$ means, and what $\Delta$ means.

Comment: If my logic is correct, would this statement be equivalent to showing that the $∆$ operator is symmetric? Assuming that the double arrow is If and only If (sometimes written as iff, also known as a biconditional I believe?)... I think the $∆$ operator is known as the Symmetric Set difference.. So if this statement is true maybe that's why it is called Symmetric! But ye you need to define your symbols please :)

Comment: "I don't idea." is an incomplete sentence, thus doesn't signify anything.

Comment: @DanielOnMSE , you are right about ∆, this is symmetric difference. Also my teacher use plus '+' instead of ∆. <=> is probably what you meant. I know it's totally not a =.

Comment: Ye so chances are the double sided arrow is an implication that works both ways. A logical implication is this: "If x Then y" is written as x => y (read as x implies y). If both x => y AND y => x are True statements then we write x <=> y (or y <=> x). This can be read as x implies y and y implies x. Or I believe this is generally read as x if and only if y (or y if and only if  x). Because if x is true then y must be and vice versa.

Comment: I feel like the "+" operator is more analogous to a Union of sets rather than the Symmetric difference of two sets. So if I were you I would ask your teacher what the meaning of his symbol is?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.
Prove A $\Delta$B = (A $\cup$ B) - (A $\cap$ B).